# Could not create tablespace in PostgreSQL 9.1

Tags: psql, tablespace

I can not create tablespace in PostgreSQL 9.1

```
Create tablespace rgu location '/postgresql';
ERROR: directory "/postgresql" does not exist.
```

The rights to this folder are provided `drwxrwxrwx` postgres
[image]

Comment: is it a directory or symbolic link?..

Comment: it is  a directory

Comment: in your screeshot you run all as root, what does `su -c "ls -al /" postgres` show?..

Comment: Yes, everything is the same

Comment: Did you come up with a solution for this? I am experiencing a similar problem.

Comment: Are you trying to create the directory on the right place/environment? May be you start the postgres server as a docker container and connect to it from local host??